# В DataGridView появляются лишние строки после применения фильтра TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

Возникла проблема с отображением отфилтрованных через TreeView строк в DataGridVIew.

Суть проблемы: после применения фильтра, например, по условию сделать `Rows.Visible = true` строки, которые соответствуют, а несоответствие `Rows.Visible = false`, появляются другие строки, причем отображаются не полностью, а только их обновлённые ячейки, как на примере: [image: пример ошибки]
Важно отметить, что обновление DataGridView у меня происходит не в main потоке, т.е. я постоянно обновляю что-то в таблице по заданному thread_delay_time.

Код, который отрабатывает в методе TreeView1_AfterSelect:

```
private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    Classes.TreeViewFilter treeViewFilter = new Classes.TreeViewFilter();
    treeViewFilter.Filter(this);
}
```

Кусок из класса TreeViewFilter:

```
class TreeViewFilter
    {
        public void Filter(MainForm mainForm)
        {
            switch (mainForm.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
            {
                case "Категория":
                    mainForm.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case "МЭД":
                    mainForm.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 1)
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        else
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Воздух":
                    mainForm.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 2)
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                            mainForm.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

... и тд, все остальное по аналогии

Фильтрация мне нужна не только по After_Select, но и динамическая, что бы при выбранном узле TreeView в DataGridView отображался только нужный набор строк, реализовывал я это через `DataGridView1_CellValueChanged` и новый поток `private void ThreeViewMarker()` в котором все делалось по аналогии, но с небольшими изменениями, т.к. выскакивал exception:

```
 Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                switch (TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text)
                {
                    case "Категория":
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                    CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                    currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "МЭД":
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 1)
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Воздух":
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value) == 2)
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                        CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                        currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
                            }
                        }
```

... и тд, дальше по аналогии.

Естественно, этот метод так же не отрабатывает как следует, появляются лишние строки.

Имеет место быть еще и странное поведение в целом, проблема проявляется при масштабировании окна немного другим образом и появляется первая строка из набора строк:

[image: Ошибка появляется при масштабировании]

На .gif метод с динамическим обновлением `DataGridView` **отключен**! Результат простого `After_Select`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с этим бороться и что я не учел при подобной фильтрации.

Для решения проблемы я пробовал это:

```
string columnName = "type"; // or other column
string filterValue = "2";   // or other value
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", columnName, filterValue);
(mainForm.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Но после отрабатывания перестают опрашиваться скрытые строки в таблице (будто бы они пропадают из DataSource или что-то вроде того). Мне же нужен опрос по всем строкам всегда, будь то они видимы или нет, иначе, без этого не получится реализовать динамическое обновление таблицы, когда в строке устанавливается значение, соответствующее условию "показывания" при выбранном узле.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я понял, лишняя строка, которая появляется - это выделенная строка в CurrencyManager.
Я смог найти два подхода к решению этой проблемы:

- Отключить CurrencyManager в начале метода фильтрации по дереву

  ```
  CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext [dataGridView1.DataSource];
  currencyManager.SuspendBinding();
  ```

  Отключение сделает недоступным некоторые возможности, например CurrentRow, CurrentCell и, возможно, еще что-то.
- Переключать выделение на одну из строк, которые должны быть видимыми.

  ```
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[columnNumber, visibleRowNumber];
  ```

  Однако, этот вариант не работает в случае, когда все строки должны быть скрыты.